# Processing generate multidimensional array

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, processing

Well im learning processing and i have experience with javascript etc but i have an issue

```
int [][] generateNewBoard(int boardSize) {
  int [][] newBoard = new int[boardSize][boardSize];
  
    for (int x = 0; x < boardSize*3; x++) {
      for (int y = 0; y < boardSize*3; y++) {
       if (x < boardSize && y < boardSize) {
        newBoard[y][x] = 0;
       } else if (x < boardSize*2 && y < boardSize*2) {
         newBoard[y][x] = 1;
       } else {
         newBoard[y][x] = 0;
       }
    }
  }

  
  return newBoard;
}
```

i want this to generate this:

```
{
    {0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0},
    {0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0},
    {0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0},
    {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
    {1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1},
    {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
    {0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0},
    {0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0},
    {0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0},
}
```

In javascript it would be newBoard[y][x] = 0; but it seems like processing does not like that because i get an error saying "java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException" and i tried many variations but cant really find a solution so im seeking ur help!

Any feedback is welcome!

Edit: full error message for stack trace

```
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
    at processing.core.PApplet.runSketch(PApplet.java:10168)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 3 out of bounds for length 3
    at Solitaire.generateNewBoard(Solitaire.java:77)
    at Solitaire.<init>(Solitaire.java:29)
    ... 7 more
RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
```

Comment: Okay so i changed ```int [][] newBoard = {};``` to ```int [][] newBoard = new int[boardSize][boardSize];``` so if boardSize is 3 it would be a array with 3 sub arrays and in these arrays will be 3 items right?

Comment: Array indexes in Java are zero based, so for a three element array, indexes are 0, 1 and 2. Your error message says you are trying to access element with index = 3. Refer to: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Comment: Ahh that makes sense, i should have known that my bad haha, anyways that was the issue, thanks for ur help @Abra